# Android gradle 3.0.0 - Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

After updating android studio to 3.0 and switching to `gradle plugin 3.0.0` I am getting this error:

```
Gradle '...' project refresh failed
    Error:Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

The problems appears both in all my old projects but brand new ones as well. 
Any Idea on what is causing this? Gradle 2.3.3 works fine

my project `build.gradle`:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967831/org-gradle-api-uncheckedioexception-failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem after my studio upgraded from 2.3.3 to 3.0, of course I have upgraded my project gradle plugin version from 2.3.3 to 3.0.

I think the gradle plugin jar file is broken and not readable or any unknow exception happened, so delete it and re-download.

What I propose is to,

- Delete gradle folder in studio installed path (mine is D:\Tool\android-studio\gradle),
- Re-sync your project. The project will re-download its dependencies.

If the problem is not solved, try to delete your gradle user data (mine is C:\Users\tea\.gradle) and then re-sync project.

Comment: Same problem for me upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1 and this solution worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's solved in MAC

1. uninstall `gradle` brew uninstall `gradle`
2. `brew install gradle`
3. `cd ~/[users].gradle/`
4. `rm -r *`
5. synchronize android studio

Answer (score 0):

Pls. see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) official tutorial on gradle migration to 3.0.

Had similar issue - the reason was that in manifest was written `meta_data` instead of `meta-data`. For older gradle it was just warning, for new - fatal error.

Maybe you have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been experiencing this error with gradle 4.0.0 and 4.0.1. Unfortunately deleting the `Users/<user>/.gradle` folder didn't do the trick. I had to uninstall and re-install android studio along with deleting the `Users/<user>/.gradle` folder again

Answer (score 0):

For me worked to delete everything in:

```
C:\Users\userName\.gradle
```