# Android studio 3.1.4 unexpected end of ZLIB input stream error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111364/android-gradle-3-0-0-unexpected-end-of-zlib-input-stream/51076973) but it is still not working 
that include

- deleting gradle folder in android studio
- deleting gradle user data

here is error log

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

thanks
P.S I'M USING LINUX ;-)

Comment: In the last answer of the solution you linked, @GoltsevEugen said, "...in manifest was written meta_data instead of meta-data".  

Have you looked at that to see if that is the problem?

Comment: have no meta-data string in the manifest.xml file, any idea?

Comment: in-fact adding meta-data tag DON'T change the error NOR has a solution

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping that would help your issue too. I'll keep digging.